# Editable NSTextField on Mac in Cocos2d project

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, cocos2d-iphone

I'm trying to display editable NSTextField on Mac in Cocos2d project. I run all my test code directly from AppDelegate to make test simple and eliminate all side effects. The code bellow shows red window with nice edit field. The trouble is that the field looks like without focus (text selection is gray) and is not editable (no cursor and no reaction to key strokes). I can change the text selection with mouse but that is all.

Any hint to what's wrong?

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    CCDirectorMac *director = (CCDirectorMac*) [CCDirector sharedDirector];
    [glView_ setFrameSize:NSMakeSize(1024,768)]; 
    [director setOpenGLView:glView_];
    [director setResizeMode:kCCDirectorResize_AutoScale];
    [glView_ setFrameSize:NSMakeSize(window_.frame.size.width,window_.frame.size.height-20)]; 
    [window_ setContentAspectRatio:NSMakeSize(1024,768)];
    [window_ setAcceptsMouseMovedEvents:NO];

    [self addOverlayWindow];

    //[director runWithScene:[MCGameScene scene]/*[HelloWorldLayer scene]*/];
}

- (void) addOverlayWindow;
{
    NSRect windowRect = [[window_ contentView] frame] ;
    NSWindow* uiWindow  = [[NSWindow alloc]  initWithContentRect:windowRect
                                     styleMask:NSBorderlessWindowMask
                                       backing:NSBackingStoreBuffered defer:YES];
    [uiWindow setBackgroundColor: [NSColor redColor/*clearColor*/]];
    [uiWindow setOpaque:NO];

    NSView* uiView = [[[NSView alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(0, 0, windowRect.size.width, windowRect.size.height)] autorelease];
    [uiView translateOriginToPoint:NSMakePoint(100, uiView.bounds.size.height/2)];
    uiView.wantsLayer   = YES;

    [uiWindow setContentView:uiView];

    NSTextField *textField;
    textField = [[NSTextField alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(0, 0, 800, 80)];
    [textField setFont:[NSFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica Bold" size:60]];
    [textField setStringValue:@"My XXXXXXXXX Label"];
    [textField setBezeled:YES];
    [textField setDrawsBackground:YES];
    [textField setEditable:YES];
    [textField setSelectable:YES];
    [textField setEnabled:YES];

    [uiView addSubview:textField];

    // None of these combinations works...
    //    [textField becomeFirstResponder];
    //    [uiWindow setInitialFirstResponder:textField];
//    [uiWindow makeFirstResponder:textField];
    //[window_ makeFirstResponder:textField];
      [window_ setInitialFirstResponder:textField];
//    [uiView setInitialFirstResponder:textField];
    //    [uiView makeFirstResponder:textField];

    [window_ addChildWindow:uiWindow ordered:NSWindowAbove];
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help,
--Josef